# Regex mis match after any number of words

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

So I have a pattern like

/a/b/c/Dont Want This/tag.

Now the pattern can have any chars after a/b/
So some other patterns would be like:

1. /a/b/c/d/Dont Want This/tag
2. /a/b/c/d/e/.../x/Dont Want This/random stuff/tag

My regex would use negative lookahead to check that "Dont Want This" doesn't appear in string and also check that the string ends with "tag".

My problem is that I am stuck as to how to allow for all possible stuff that appears before "Dont Want This" and after "/a/b?

PS: Using Python's re module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So given `/a/b/c/d/e/.../x/Dont Want This/random stuff/tag`, do you want to match `/c/d/e/.../x/`?

Comment: I want a  regex that would match any pattern which has "/a/b/c/d/../tag" but not "Dont Want This" anywhere between "/a/b" and "/tag". Also there can be any number of literals(other than one mentioned in previous line)  after "/a/b" and before "/tag" at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex based on negative lookahead:

```
^/a/b(?!.*/Dont Want This).*/tag$
```

`(?!.*/Dont Want This)` will disallow `/Dont Want This` appearing in inputs that start with `/a/b` and end with `/tag`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS0wT4/1)

Comment: Do you mean `^\/a\/b(?!.*\/Dont Want This).*\/tag$` as you need to escape the `\`

Comment: I am afraid , I think I have not been clear in stating the requirement. The regex should not match if "Dont Want This" appears anywhere between "/a/b" and "/tag". So any string that starts with "/a/b" and ends with "/tag" and doesn't have "Dont Want This" anywhere in between is fine and should match.

Comment: @Harsh: In python you don't need to escape `/`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, I had no idea :)

Comment: @amrx: Isn't this regex already doing this? It matches input that starts with `/a/b` and ends with `/tag`. It will not match if `/Dont Want This/` appears in the middle otherwise it is a match. Can you check my demo link as well.

Comment: @anubhava, sorry my bad, the demo link is broken and the explanation "will disallow given text appearing for strings that start with /a/b and end with /tag" makes as if its blocking the match when string starts with "a/b/" and ends with "/tag". Tried it out in interpreter, this is what I required. Thanks.

Comment: Oops sorry my mistake due to bad copy/paste, fixed demo link.